# avr-gcc: is there an UB sanitizer

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, sanitizer

Trying to use the UB sanitizer for AVR target gives:

```
avr-gcc -Wall  -mmcu=attiny1614 -fsanitize=undefined  bm02.c 
/usr/local/lib/gcc/avr/10.0.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld: cannot find
-lubsan collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can one build the avr-gcc with UBsan support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Currently, avr-g++ has no full C++ support, and for such targets, the toplevel [configure.ac switches off libsanitizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=configure.ac;h=df2af18f9bdc6a6de3458864f8e5d2d3db2ee875;hb=7c46e71d016c86971ac26c6fa38d76482859f296#l2234).  This is because libsanitizer is written in C++, cf. [ubsan sources](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=libsanitizer/ubsan).